# Increment numbers in a textarea using a RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textarea (with id 'work') with successive numbers in square brackets as follows:

```
[6] [7] [8] [9] [10]
```

I want that on pressing a button, each of these should increase by 1, like this:

```
[7] [8] [9] [10] [11]
```

How do I do this in Javascript? I wrote the following, but it does not work:

```
addOne = function() {
    var work = document.getElementById('work');
    var re = /\[\d+\]/g
    var arr = re.match(work.value);
    var len = arr.length;
    var pat = /\d+/
    var begin = pat.exec(arr[0]); 
    var last = pat.exec(arr[len-1]);
    for (i=begin;i<=last;i++) {
        var re1 = new RegExp("[i]"); 
        var re2 = new RegExp("[i++]");
        var newval = work.value.replace(re1,re2);
        work.value = newval;
    }
}
```

The textarea may also have other text apart from these numbers. Please help me here. 
Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: RegExp is not magic/eval. Why would `i++` inside a string increase that number..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in conjunction with a RegExp and a callback function (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/veYTt/):

```
var work = document.getElementById('work');
work.value = work.value.replace(/\[(\d+)(?=\])/g, function(full_match, i) {
    return '[' + ++i;
});
```

I used `++i`, because `++i` converts `i` from a string to a number, and returns the value `i + 1`. An alternative is `(i + 1*1)`.

Explanation of the RegExp:

- `\[` matches `[`.
- `(\d+)` matches and captures any integer. This group is passed to the callback function as a second argument, which I named `i`.
- `(?=\])` is a look-ahead. It causes the pattern to match when the previously matched characters are followed by `]`.